# Is there some mechanic that prevents multiple copies of a spell in a ritual book when you have Ritual Caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, equipment

The Feat [Ritual Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/ritual-caster) doesn't seem to prohibit copying spells multiple times into the ritual book. Is there some other mechanic at play that would prevent multiple copies of the same spell from being entered into the ritual book? Or, even though it is not stated: is the ritual  book just like a normal spellbook?

Could the character just use multiple books?

Comment: Is there a reason you would try to do this? I cannot see there being any mechanical difference between a book with *tiny hut* written once, and one with it written twice. If there is something I'm missing here, it needs to be included in the question because that is the problem youre actually trying to solve.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov While I can’t imagine what purpose this could serve either, and James’s reasoning may well point at other confusion that suggests this would be useful (when it, as far as I can tell, is not), and we could clarify and correct that, ultimately, *this is an answerable question*. We might *want* to know why, but we don’t *need* to know why. And if James is, in fact, confused and thinking this would be useful, they can easily ask that in another question if it comes to that.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Thomas already asked that; there is no good reason to reiterate that question. Multiple comments asking for the same clarification tends to do far more harm than good; see Meta discussions of “help piles” for more information.

Answer (score 8):

As noted in the comments, I don't see any benefit to having the spell copied multiple times in the same book (please correct me if I'm wrong). So long as the correct amount of resources are spent for each copying (or GM could rule reduced resources based on available experience, knowledge etc.) there is nothing stopping you from making multiple copies in the same book.

Extra Credit: The character could definitely use multiple books, and depending on the campaign it can be a great idea. If a spell book is stollen/ lost/ destroyed/etc. having the backup copy would be invaluable to allow for continued spell casting.

Comment: As far as costs go, subsequent copies are cheaper. From 2 hours + 50 g per level, down to 1 hour + 10g per level, if you're using your own book as source for the duplicate, that is.

Answer (score 6):

### You can copy the same spell in the ritual book multiple times. But you can already cast a ritual spell multiple times when you have inscribed it once.

Nothing in the feat and no other mechanic prevents you from copying the same spell into your ritual book multiple times.

But most of the time, doing so is a waste of resources because when you have one copy of the spell in your ritual book, you can already cast it as a [ritual](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals).

> Certain spells have a special tag: ritual. Such a spell can be cast
> following the normal rules for spellcasting, or the spell can be cast
> as a ritual. The ritual version of a spell takes 10 minutes longer to
> cast than normal. It also doesn't expend a spell slot

So you can already cast the spell multiple times when you have it as a ritual. To learn more about rituals, make sure to read the [Ritual Section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals) in the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules).

Comment: The only time I can see copying a spell more than once being useful is when you're writing a backup spellbook to protect yourself in case of theft, damage, or other loss. Of course, this implies duplicating it in a _different_ book, not just duplicating the spell on the same book.